# How to copy rows from one ag-grid to second ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I've two ag-grids on my UI. 
Ag-grid 1 has 4 rows. Ag-grid 2 has 5 rows. Both ag-grids have same columns. 
I want to copy all the rows from Ag-grid 2 to Ag-grid 1 on some button click.
How can I do that?

Expected result:
On button click.

1. Ag-grid 1 should have 9 rows (4 original rows and 5 rows which are copied from Ag-grid 2).
2. Ag-grid 2 should have 0 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this sort of function:

```
move(){
  var rows = this.agGrid2.api.getModel().rowsToDisplay.map(e=>e.data)
  this.agGrid1.api.updateRowData({add: rows})
  this.agGrid2.api.setRowData([])
}
```

here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3FkhOboA0hOS8QPsizY2?p=preview)

This answers exactly as you asked, however, it sounds like you or someone else who is interested in a moving type function from one grid to another, might find it useful to use `getSelectedRows()` instead of `getModel()`